# Adjusting chromecast tv volume through mobile device volume up down buttons

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have integrated chromecast in my app.When video is running on tv i am able to change volume by clicking on chromcast icon which shows dialog box which allows to adjust volume.But i am not able to adjust the volume through my mobile device volume keys which are working fine when playing video locally.How can I program it in such a way that i am able to adjust volume through volume up down keys of mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is in front, then your activity can override dispatchKeyEvent() and use the Cast SDK Apis to increase or decrease the volume:

```
Cast.CastApi.setVolume(mApiClient, volume)
```

If your app is not in front, then you need to use `MediaRouter` with either `MediaSession` or `RemoteControlClient` to achieve that; that is more involved , you can take a look at this [library](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) to see how it does that.